# Multiple STRING_AGG on multiple join columns causes bloated aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I've got a table in my MSSQL server, lets call it `blogPost`. I've also got two tag tables, lets call them `fooTag` and `barTag`. The tag tables are used to tag the `blogPost` table which are identically structured.

```
blogPost

| postId | title               |        body |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+
| 1      | The life on a query | lorem ipsum |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+

fooTag and barTag

| postId | tagName      |
+--------+--------------+
| 1      | sql          |
| 1      | query        |
| 1      | select-query |
+--------+--------------+
```

I want to get a single blogpost along with all it's tags in a single row so then `STRING_AGG()` feels suitable to make a query like this:

```sql
SELECT blogPost.*, STRING_AGG(fooTag.tagName, ';') as [fooTags], STRING_AGG(barTag.tagName, ';') as [barTags]
FROM blogPost
LEFT JOIN fooTag ON blogPost.postId = fooTag.postId
LEFT JOIN barTag ON blogPost.postId = barTag.postId
WHERE postId = 1
GROUP BY blogPost.postId, title, body
```

When making this query I'd expect to get the result

```
| postId | title               |        body | fooTags                 | barTags                 |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1      | The life on a query | lorem ipsum | sql;query;select-query | sql;query;select-query |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

But I'm getting this result instead where bar tags (i.e. the last STRING_AGG selected) are duplicated.

```
| postId | title               |        body | fooTags                 | barTags                                       |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| 1      | The life on a query | lorem ipsum | sql;query;select-query; | sql;sql;sql;query;query;query;select-query;select-query;select-query |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Putting `barTags` last in the SELECT statement makes it so that `barTags` gets the duplicates instead of `fooTags`. The amount of duplicates created seem to be bound to the amount of rows columns being aggregated together in the first `STRING_AGG` result column, so if `fooTags` has 5 rows to aggregate together there will be 5 duplicates of each `barTag` in the `barTags` column in the result.

How would I get the result I want without duplicates?

Comment: where is the bartag column

Comment: Whoopise. It's fixed now. Did a bit too much copy paste.

Comment: Thanks for asking this! Saved me work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is caused by each row in `fooTags` creating that many rows of `barTags` in the `JOIN`, hence the duplication. You can work around this issue by performing the `STRING_AGG` in the `footags` and `bartags` tables *before* `JOIN`ing them:

```
SELECT blogPost.*, f.tags as [fooTags], b.tags as [barTags]
FROM blogPost
LEFT JOIN (SELECT postId, STRING_AGG(tagName, ';') AS tags
           FROM fooTag
           GROUP BY postId) f ON blogPost.postId = f.postId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT postId, STRING_AGG(tagName, ';') AS tags
           FROM barTag
           GROUP BY postId) b ON blogPost.postId = b.postId
WHERE postId = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify the query like so:

```
SELECT blogPost.*, ca1.*, ca2.*
FROM blogPost
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(tagName, ';')
    FROM fooTag
    WHERE blogPost.postId = fooTag.postId
) AS ca1(fooTags)
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(tagName, ';')
    FROM barTag
    WHERE blogPost.postId = barTag.postId
) AS ca2(barTags)
WHERE postId = 1
```

No GROUP BY required, in your case it'll be an expensive operation.

Comment: Since you're specifically saying that no GROUP BY is required. Why would that be an argument compared to having a GROUP BY like @Nick's answer?

Comment: @hannes on second thought, there is no need of the outer group by in the other answer. I'll edit it for him.

Comment: @SalmanA thanks for the edit. It wouldn't have hurt but it definitely shouldn't have been there.